# Garlic and Onion in Hindu Text

Tags: food

So I know usually speaking Garlic and Onion are considered impure. However, from these news articles: https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/us?back=1 and [https://lovingfoods.medium.com/why-onion-and-garlic-is-not-vegetarian-loving-foods-23af0fcf1898#:~:text=Not%20only%20this%20some%20people,and%20garlic%20have%20medicinal%20properties](https://lovingfoods.medium.com/why-onion-and-garlic-is-not-vegetarian-loving-foods-23af0fcf1898#:%7E:text=Not%20only%20this%20some%20people,and%20garlic%20have%20medicinal%20properties). state that Aryuvedic scripture acknowledge their medical benefits and just shouldn't be eaten in excess like say tomato. I couldn't find any scriptural references however, can you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ayurveda texts like sushruta samhita and charaka samhita do have chapters detailing out medicinal value of every animal and plant including onion and garlic but these are chapters for an ayurvedic doctor to prepare medicines or prescribe a medical diet to patient for specific illness. These are not verses dealing with regular food.

The list of foods which are wholesome or can be consumed regularly are mentioned in other chapters and these foods do not include onion and garlic and are consistent with foods listed in smritis :

> **charaka samhita sutrasthana ch 5 :**
> *12.Shashtika rice, shali rice, green gram, rock-salt, emblic myrobalan barley, rain water, milk, ghee, flesh of jangala animals and
> honey **may be habitually taken**.*
>
> **charaka samhita sutrasthana ch 27 :**
> *3-(1). The experts hold that the articles of food and drink which are of a **pleasing** color, **smell**, taste and touch, taken
> systematically, constitute the Life of all living beings known also as
> creatures. This view is the result of practical observation.*
>
> **charaka samhita sutrasthana ch 25 lists ginger among roots (not onion/garlic)** :
> *38. The most beneficial among food articles are thus:*
>
> *Red rice is the best among all cereal crops having bristles, green gram among pulses,*
>
> *rain water among various types of drinking water,*
>
> *rock salt among salts,*
>
> *jiwanti among pot herbs,*
>
> *antelope among meat of animals,*
>
> *common quail among meat of birds,*
>
> *the iguana among meat of burrowing animals,*
>
> *rohita among fishes,*
>
> *cow ghee among ghee, cow milk among milk,*
>
> *tila  oil among fats of vegetable sources,*
>
> *lard (wild hog's fat) among the fats of marshy animals,*
>
> *fat of chuluki among fish fat,*
>
> *fat of pakahamsa (white swan) among fats of aquatic birds,*
>
> *the fat of wild hen among fats of gallinaceous types of birds,*
>
> *the fat of goat among fats of branch-eating animals,*
>
> **ginger among rhizomes and roots**,
>
> *grapes among fruits,*
>
> *and sugar among the products of sugarcane.*
>
> *In this manner, various natural food articles have been identified to be the most
> wholesome in their class.*

Comment: What about the verses prepared by a doctor can you please answer the question?

Comment: I am not able to find anything in your first link. The conclusion in the 2nd link i.e. "eat onion and garlic but as medicine. not as food." is close to what is mentioned in texts like susruta, charaka,etc. Difference between food and medicine is that food is eaten every day full plate whereas medicine is taken only when a person falls sick that too only a spoon quantity under medical supervision

Comment: Yes, but the verses for medication, please. I won't be eating it or anything like that just interested.

Comment: charaka samhita chikitsa sthana 5.95 talks about garlic milk for curing some disorders - "This milk will quickly cure Vata Gulma, misperistalsis, sciatica, irregular fever, abscess, cardiac disorders, abscess and edema. Thus has been described ‘The Garlic Milk’."

Comment: Cool very nice!